# Need advice as I am trying to use drag and drop grid as well as a bootstrap modal on asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have a bootstrap modal on my form. I am using it as a static pop up to show extra information about some data. The data is from an asp.net gridview that the user selects. One of our grid requires user to make up their own sequence of how to show data (basically a sort) but it is stored in the db as a sequence number. After researching the best way to allow users to sequence I cam across drag and drop using jquery (bare in mind the modal also uses a different version of jquery). I have managed to implement this via the following way.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.3.3.7.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/bootstrap.3.3.7.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $x = jQuery.noConflict();
       $x(function () {
            $x("[id*=gvCurrencies]").sortable({
                items: 'tr:not(tr:first-child)',
                cursor: 'pointer',
                axis: 'y',
                dropOnEmpty: false,
                start: function (e, ui) {
                    ui.item.addClass("selected");
                },
                stop: function (e, ui) {
                    ui.item.removeClass("selected");
                },
                receive: function (e, ui) {
                    $(this).find("tbody").append(ui.item);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.24/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

Could someone please have a look and this and confirm it this is a preferred way of doing it. Basically i will download all the js/styles into my project however as I have never tried to reference multiple different versions of jquery files I am unsure if this is advisable. This does work, but last thing i want is for it to fall down after it is released.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whats with all the dislikes, anyway so after researching for a while it seems to be standard to apply a character so you can differentiate between the jquery files.